# Update SKU Qty from 1 list to another Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I would like one list of qtys to update the other list with its new qty.

Match SKU & Location before updating

see link 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FyR_uGu3WbV1QcrRUWdyL5qCTjpATjSwc9ZV7IWBh4M/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(F2:F&G2:G, {A2:A&B2:B, C2:C}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]